# grep contents of one list with another

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I have 2 files and I want to grep on them

List1

```
ACY1
RPL3
RPL4
```

List2

```
1   ABHD14A-ACY1
2   ACY1
3   RPL34
4   RPL21
5   RPL3
6   RPL41
```

I tried something like this

`grep -Fwf list1.txt list2.txt` and got this

```
1   ABHD14A-ACY1
2   ACY1
5   RPL3
```

My list1 did not have ABHD14A-ACY1. Is there a way in grep I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `-w` option makes `grep` match whole words. Unfortunately, `ABHD14A-ACY1` matches `ACY1` due to the dash. You might want to add a space to the pattern file like

```
sed 's/^/ /' file1 | grep -Fwf- file2
2   ACY1
5   RPL3
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-w` switch returns matches that form whole words.

The reason that it returns `ABHD14A-ACY1` and not `RPL41` is because `ACY1` is at the end of the first and second lines whereas `RPL4` is neither at the beginning nor end of any lines nor is it followed by a non-word constituent character which means anything other than a letter, number, or underscore. This is covered in the `man` page for `grep`.

To test this, if you add a `1` the end of the first line so that it's `1   ABHD14A-ACY11` and remove the 1 from the end of the sixth line so that it's `6   RPL4` then your output will look like this:

```
2   ACY1
5   RPL3
6   RPL4
```

There isn't a way to not return the first line with the exact command that you have or with just calling `grep` on it's own. You'd have to pipe it into `sed` to remove the first line:

```
grep -Fwf list1.txt list2.txt | sed '/ABHD14A/d'
```

Or pipe it into `awk` to only print what `grep` returns after the line containing what you don't want to match:

```
grep -Fwf list1.txt list2.txt | awk 'NR>1'
```

Or pipe it into grep -v to exclude the first line:

```
grep -Fwf list1.txt list2.txt | grep -v ^1
```

There are other ways to do it but those are the easiest and allow you to just pipe what you have already have.